# Date format with Quickpart Database in Word

Tags: ms-word, word-field

I try to change the date format in a quickpart database function.

The format is in American (mm/d/yyyy) but i want to change in the French format (dd.MM.yyyy).

This is my code :

> DATABASE \d "C:\Users\taagede1\Dropbox\Samaritains\Soldes et
>   indemnités\2018\Total soldes.xlsx" \c
>   "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data
>   Source=C:\Users\taagede1\Dropbox\Samaritains\Soldes et
>   indemnités\2018\Total soldes.xlsx;Mode=Read;Extended
>   Properties=\"HDR=YES;IMEX=1;\";Jet OLEDB:System database=\"\";Jet
>   OLEDB:Registry Path=\"\";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=37;Jet OLEDB:Database
>   Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global
>   Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password=\"\";Jet
>   OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt
>   Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet
>   OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet
>   OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo
>   Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass
>   ChoiceField Validation=False" \s "SELECT `Quoi`, `Date` , `Heure
>   Début`, `Heure Fin`, `Total` FROM `Engagements$` WHERE ((`NomPrenom` =
>   'AubortLoic') AND (`Payé` IS NULL )) ORDER BY `Date`" \l "26" \b "191"
>   \h

This is the result:

[image]

I have tried to add this:

```
{ DATABASE [\@ "dd.MM.yyyy"] \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

But i have a very ugly result (all buggy)

Comment: Try removing the square brackets around the date format (although I don't think it will help). Test formatting the data the way you want to receive it within the data source (an Excel file) and see if that makes any difference. Also, is the document text formatted as French? And how about the default date in the Windows environment: American or French?

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks for your answer! unfortunaly this is not working.
The data source (excel) is correctly formated... and the default date in windows too ( in french)

Answer (score 1):

The OLEDB driver for Excel (and Access - it's the same one) supports a limited number of functions that can be used on the data via the `Select` query, among them `Format`. It's similar, but not identical to the VBA function of the same name.

In my test the following `Select` phrase worked (extracted from the `Database` field code for better visibility):

```
 \s "SELECT Quoi, Format([Date], 'dd.MM.yyyy') AS FrDate, Heure
  Début, Heure Fin, Total FROM Engagements$ WHERE ((NomPrenom = 'AubortLoic') AND (Payé IS NULL )) ORDER BY Date
```

Note that the date format is in single, not double quotes. You can use anything for the alias (the column header), except another field name. So it can't be `Date` if that's the field name in the data source. It could be `Le Date`, but in this case, due to the spaces, it would have to be in square brackets: `[Le Date]`.